# EXCEL Count number of weeks in month based on date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to look up a value in a matrix based on a given date. The matrix has the first day of the week along the vertical axis, and the first day of the month along the horizontal axis.

For a given day, e.g. 31/08/15 I would like to match the exact date to the vertical axis of the matrix (i.e. 31/08/15), and the month to the horizontal axis (1/08/15).

So in the example below, an input of 31/08/15 should provide an output of 3.

```
    01/06/2015  01/07/2015  01/08/2015  01/09/2015
03/08/2015  1   0   0   0
10/08/2015  0   2   0   0
17/08/2015  0   0   3   0
24/08/2015  0   0   0   4
31/08/2015  0   0   3   0
```

I am trying and failing with index and match formulae. 
I have tried the following:
=index(area where to look, match(31/08/15,first column,0),match(and(month(31/08/15),year(31/08/15)),(and(month(first row),year(first row)),0)

Hope this is clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) with two [MATCH functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) top supply both the row and column.

[image: INDEX(MATCH, MATCH)]

The formula in D8 is,

```
=INDEX($B$2:$E$6,MATCH(C8,$A$2:$A$6,0),MATCH(DATE(YEAR(C8),MONTH(C8),1),$B$1:$E$1,0))
```

I'm a little concerned about the dates matching exactly down column A but a little maths manipulation with the [WEEKDAY function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Weekday-Function-05D360D7-2C3F-4691-9448-C96EA0351940) would take care of that.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$E$6,MATCH(C9-WEEKDAY(C9, 2)+1,$A$2:$A$6,0),MATCH(DATE(YEAR(C9),MONTH(C9),1),$B$1:$E$1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$E$6,MATCH(DATE(2015,8,31),$A$2:$A$6,),MATCH(DATE(2015,8,1),$B$1:$E$1,))
```